# Why 150 scroll contexts are created in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, scroll, lucene

I have some time-series data which I used to put in one elasticsearch index. Now I have shifted to 1 index per day with index prefix `logs-`.

Currently, there are 60 indices and I am making scroll call to `logs-*`. But I found that after 4 calls, I was getting error `too many scroll contexts`.

```
GET _nodes/stats/indices/search
"scroll_current": 150
```

It seems with each call 150 scroll contexts are being created. Why is it so? The number of shards for each index is 5 if it matters.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you tell us how you're doing scrolls and show some of your client code.

Answer (score 0):

I would have posted a comment instead, but can't due to low rep. Can this help ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#_clear_scroll_api

Also you can try and tweak that value in you cluster setting :
`search.max_open_scroll_context`

Comment: I knew that but wanted to know why its happening

Answer (score 0):

I dont really get why you would have so many. But it had happend to me that clients were starting scrolls and not finalizing them, then this contexts would remain open until their expiration time of a default of 5 minutes. This would even kill the cluster if the scrolls had a high number of items matching.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a scroll_current around 65 for a single scroll.

By testing on a test index with no tokenizers definition I had for each scroll exactly 1 scroll_current. Then by adding a definition of the index with some fields and an ngram tokenizer I've had back the high scroll_current.

My hypotesis is that the tokenizer has to consume more resources.